# Impossible insert data into mysql table with Point data type using Gorm customized data type

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

In my mysql db I have table "restaurant". This table has field "position" with type POINT. So, when I try to insert data in to table using customized data type like in docs https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-From-SQL-Expr/Context-Valuer and to get inserted id, but I got error:

> "sql: converting argument $6 type: unsupported type models.Point, a struct"

I'm new in go and sorry for my English.

Code:

Model

```
type Restaurant struct {
    ID            uint
    Name          string          `json:"name"`
    EmployeeId    uint            `json:"employee_id"`
    Phone         string          `json:"phone"`
    Address       string          `json:"address"`
    ImagesUrl     *string         `json:"images_url"`
    Position      Point           `json:"position" gorm:"type:Point"`
    WorkDays      string          `json:"work_days"`
    StartWorkTime string          `json:"start_work_time"`
    EndWorkTime   string          `json:"end_work_time"`
    Blocked       bool            `json:"blocked"`
}
```

Point type

```
type Point struct {
    LatLong string `json:"lat_long"`
    //Lat float64
    //Long float64
}
func (p *Point) Scan(v interface{}) error {
    fmt.Printf("Scan value %v", v)
    return nil
}

func (p Point) GormDataType() string {
    return "geometry"
}

func (p Point) GormValue(ctx context.Context, db *gorm.DB) clause.Expr {
    return clause.Expr{
        SQL:  "ST_PointFromText(?, 4326)",
        Vars: []interface{}{fmt.Sprintf("POINT(%s)", p.LatLong)},
    }
}
```

body request data:

```
{
    "name": "Restaurant 1",
    "employee_id": 9,
    "phone": "123465",
    "address": "Test Address 91",
    "work_days": "sdfsfsd",
    "start_work_time": "00:00:00",
    "end_work_time": "00:00:00",
    "position": {
        "lat_long": "38.590559 68.755866"
    }
}
```

Calling method after parsing body to Restaurant type

```
func NewRestaurant(restaurant *Restaurant) (uint, error) {

    err := GetDB().Create(restaurant).Error

    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return restaurant.ID, nil
}
```

dependency

```
import (
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)
```

gorm build this query :

```
INSERT INTO `restaurant` 
(`name`,`employee_id`,`phone`,`address`,`images_url`,`position`,`work_days`,`start_work_time`,`end_work_time`,`blocked`) 
VALUES 
("Restaurant 1",9,"123465","Test Address 91",NULL,"{38.590559 68.755866}","sdfsfsd","00:00:00","00:00:00",false)
```

Comment: See this https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-From-SQL-Expr-Context-Valuer

Comment: @Man make sure you're using gorm2 and not gorm1.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava you've just linked to the section that OP is referencing and the code example in the link matches the code in the question. If you see some specific difference in there you ought to point it out.

Comment: @mkopriva  my dependency: 
"gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"

Comment: @Man by gorm2 I mean the new version of gorm, saying you have "gorm.io/gorm" doesn't reveal anything about the version you have installed. The reason you should use v2 is because the support for the [`GormValuerInterface`](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#GormValuerInterface) was added in [v2](https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html#CRUD-From-SQL-Expr-Context-Valuer), v1 does not supported that feature which, if you're using v1, *would* be the reason for the error you're seeing.

Comment: @mkopriva   yes, it was because of the version. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot